# How to select referencing rows in order?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select rows in my table, which correspond to each other.
I have this structure

[image: SQL Screen]

And I would like to select all rows where `32` and `33` are corresponding.

This script

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE sender = '$this' AND receiver = '$friend';
```

Only catches the one side of these rows.

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table;

Comment: or perrhaps your data set's not terribly representative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a friend request system for my site and this works fine.

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE (sender = '$this' AND receiver = '$friend') OR (sender = '$friend' AND receiver = '$this');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE t1 
JOIN MY_TABLE t2 
ON t1.id<>t2.id AND t1.sender=t2.receiver
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE t1 INNER JOIN MY_TABLE t2 ON t1.sender = t2.receiver
```

Answer (score 0):

This one selects all rows where sender = 32 (if $this = 32) and receiver is 33 (if $friend = 33), nothing else.

If you need 32 and 33 for BOTH of these cols, you have to use OR like this

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE sender = '$this' OR sender = '$friend' || receiver = '$friend' OR receiver = '$this';
```